# Which modules and Classes in Spring are responsible for Annotations implementation

Tags: spring, annotations

Spring support various annotations, which library/module/class/pattern handle annotations logic.
where spring implement annotation behaviors for @Controller, @RestController ...
Example: to add a new custom annotation, we add at-sign (@) then handle the content by using Java reflection. So in Spring Framework, how they do that and how Spring modify logic when they upgrade their version for their annotation?

@PostConstruct and @PreDestroy is handle into the class InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, so which class handle for @RestController. I want to understand how spring implementation for @RestController  because I want to add a new annotation which include @RestController and my extra logic.

Comment: Behind scene , Spring use reflection API to get the attribute values set for these annotation to perform logic accordingly. Every annotation has their own handling logic and there is no single class for handling all the annotations....

Comment: Spring handle annotations into InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor,  in case we want to inherit an annotation from spring or implement a new annotation then integrate with Spring, how we do it and how we update our version?

Comment: `InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` only handles `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` . How to implement a new annotation and integrate with Spring depends on what your annotation does.It sounds like you are asking how to solve a problem but do not tell us what is the problem you are going to solve.......

Answer (score 0):

Ok, below is a high level overview of how `@Controller` / `@RestController` work from the source codes levels . Hope that will give you some direction. For details , please refer to the related [source codes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-webmvc).

1. When `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean initialises (i.e. `afterPropertiesSet()` invokes ) ,it will find out all beans that are annotated with `@Controller`/`@RestController`. Extract the useful metadata from these beans using reflection and store them inside its `MappingRegistry`
2. When a `HttpServletRequest` is received ,invoke `RequestMappingHandlerMapping#lookupHandlerMethod()` to find out which `HandlerMethod` can handle this `HttpServletRequest` from `MappingRegistry`.
3. `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#handleInternal()` invokes for the matching `HandlerMethod` and finally use reflection to actually invoke the method on the `@Controller`/`@RestController`